# How can i notify to App for what reload the app to show another screen?

Tags: react-native

I am in **login screen** i pressed the button login so

that button have this action

```
store.dispatch({
      type: 'login',
      payload: {
        name: email.value
      },
    })
```

on the **reducers** change the value

```
export default function (state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'login':
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload,
        isLogged:true
      }
    default:
      return newState
  }
}
```

now i have to notify to **App.js** for the new change because that is depend to show the stack.screen

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store} theme={theme}>
      <Tabs store={store} />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

How can i notify to App for what reload the app to show another screen?

but never my component is updated, i was trying to update my component using useEffect but not

```
function Tabs ({ user })  {  
  const {
    data: { isLogged },
  } = useSelector((state) => state)

  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(1234546)
  }, [isLogged, user])

 return (
     <Stack.Navigator >
            { !store.getState().data.isLogged ?
              <Stack.Screen
                name="loginScreen1"
                component={HomeScreen}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
              /> :
              <Stack.Screen
                name="main"
                component={MyTabs}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />}
          </Stack.Navigator>
 )
```

Comment: It looks like your ternary is backwards. If `isLogged` is true, you should be showing the main screen.

Comment: Ok but what's the question here?

Comment: @Abe yeah but how can i reshesh that screen?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze How can i notify to App for what reload the app to show another screen?

Comment: @signup Try to use `useSelector` instead of `store.getState()`

Comment: @LeriGogsadze neither does not worked, the notify does not reach in app.js

Comment: is `isLogged` false initially?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze yes is false initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When working with States Or Redux We don't have to tell the app about when to re-render the JSX code.**

**It will be re-renders automatically** whenever the change occurs in redux or state.

But, We must have to be assured that we are **not mutating the data** in our state or redux, We always have to assign a new object to state or redux.

You can try the below changes in your code,

```
function Tabs ({ user })  {  
    const { isLogged } = useSelector((state) => state?.data)

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator >
            {
                isLogged
                ?
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name="loginScreen1"
                        component={HomeScreen}
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    />
                :
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name="main"
                        component={MyTabs}
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    />
            }
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

App navigator need to subscribe  `isLogged` state then rerender accordingly.

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const App = () => {
  const isLogged = useSelector((state) => state.isLogged);

  // Track authentication state
  useEffect(() => {}, [isLogged]);

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {!isLogged ? (
        <Stack.Screen
          name="loginScreen1"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      ) : (
        <Stack.Screen
          name="main"
          component={MyTabs}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Comment: i tried but does not worked